# Есть ли функция random с фаворитными числами?

Tags: swift, случайные-числа

В языке swift есть функция random:

```
let a = Int(arc4random_uniform(6)+1)
print(a)
```

Можно ли настроить функцию random что бы какое-то число выбиралось чаще чем другие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сомневаюсь, что такая функция где-либо существует. А в чём проблема свою написать? :D

```
integer GetRandomNumber() {
    integer five_chance = 40;

    integer three_chance = 15;

    integer result = random(100); // 0-99

    if (result <= five_chance)
        result = 5;
    else {
        result = random(100);
        if (result <= three_chance)
            result = 3;
    }
    return result;
}
```

С ходу придумал, но думаю идея подойдёт. В своей проге можешь так сделать:

```
let rand = GetRandomNumber ();
```

Comment: Мне можно что бы число 5 выпадало чаще других ,а 3 реже.

Comment: Swift не знаю, но могу написать на С++/С#/Java/Python

Comment: Ну я пока учусь писать на swift.

Comment: Напишу псевдокодом, попробуешь разобраться